# Copy/Paste Images From Web Page To Word, But They Appear As Empty Rectangles

Tags: html, wordpress, ms-word

I maintain a website that uses WordPress. From time-to-time, one of my associates opens a page in the browser, highlights some text and images, and copy/pastes it into Microsoft Word, in order to provide summaries of content to one of our higher-ups.

Ordinarily, this would be an uneventful task. However, this process is now not working. When we highlight, then copy/paste content from a page, the text will transfer over to Word, but the images will not. We simply see an empty rectangle where the images should be. [A screenshot, demonstrating that web page content that is copied, displays as nothing more than an empty rectangle when pasted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi05M.jpg)

This behavior is consistent across IE, Chrome, Opera, and Firefox. This problem occurs whether we use Microsoft Word or OpenOffice Writer. No updates were made to Word or our browsers during this time.

Of course, we want the images to display in Word, rather than empty rectangles. What can we do to make the images display in Word?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is for programming-specific questions. Questions about WordPress administration, server configuration, etc. are off topic and are more suited to the [dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).  However please review their help section first before posting to make sure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Insert image from your local system if problem persist, then its your Word issue. If local images are showing perfectly then just save a copy of image from online resource to your local system and add images from there. may be its just because of word is taking online reference for image and could not connect to internet to resolve them and showing you broken image. or the image you are adding is not supported by the older version of word such as .svg graphics. make sure you are adding images with .jpeg/jpg , .png, .gif file extension.